# Change a td in html to dropdown list in html and knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a table which gets binded with values from database. When I have a requirement that when i click on the td the td gets converted to a text box using contenteditable property of html. Now, I want to have a dropdown list instead of the text. I am using knockout and HTML 5. So can I achieve that.

Following is my code which allows me to edit

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" data-bind="htmlValue: test"></div>
```

Now, instead of text box appearing I want a dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: First off, I'd add some code to the question to show people what you have already tried if anything.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Did you [read this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for instance?

Comment: @MajorByte : Yes sir i have read. I have not tried anything as of now. but I am thinkng to take a div which has the dropdown and using visible binding show and hide the dropdown. But this looks lengthy. So I was wondering that if knockout has some options.

Comment: Easiest would be to have a <select> which is either disabled or not depending if you are editing or not.

Comment: @MajorByte Why answer in the comments?

Comment: @GôTô I don't see my last comment as a definitive answer though, more as a comment that would maybe raise some more questions. Sometimes one does not get the entire picture of what is being asked from just the question itself...